# Is the Merchant ability mandatory if you have two identical tiles?

Tags: libertalia

In Libertalia, the character card **Merchant** says:

> Discard two identical booty tiles to gain 3 doubloons, or 3 identical booty tiles to gain 5 doubloons.

**Is the ability mandatory?** (I.e. If you had 2 chests and 3 treasure maps, would you have to discard at least two of one type?)

The rules note that booty tiles in your den remain hidden until needed. If you don't discard any identical booty tiles, are you required to reveal all your tiles to prove you have no duplicates?

An official FAQ, or designer response is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. If you are able to perform the Merchant's action, you must. This does involve a certain amount of trust, since you do not have to reveal your tiles to prove that you cannot perform the action. (On that point I would paraphrase the Love Letter rulebook on a similar point, which says "Don't play with cheaters".)

From the rulebook, page 5:

> Using a special action is mandatory unless otherwise written on the card. If the action is impossible, it is ignored.